# Search function Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search

I am trying to design a search site where sections of the company's policies and ACT can be searched according to their sections areas.

For example, when user enters section 5 of policy, that part of the document should come up.

Is this possible with Sharepoint?

Comment: do u want to search documents filtering with folder name or else?

Answer (score 0):

You want to search for documents? Or Pages? Or everything?
Are these things grouped by site or something?

This question depends on your site structure.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off creating a Query Rule for this. Use and Action Term like "Section 5 of policy" and then promote Section 5 as the result. This works particularly well if what the user is looking for is an individual document.